# Query with unknown keys in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents like:

```
{   
   map:{
     key1:value1,
     key2:value2, 
     ....
    }
}
```

and I want to filter documents based on map values only, regardless the keys, something like map.* equal some value. Is it possible to do that?

MongoDB version used is 3.4

Comment: You can use `$arrayToObject` and `objectToArray` aggregation. Something like this `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      map: {
        $objectToArray: "$map"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "map.v": "value1"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      map: {
        $arrayToObject: "$map"
      }
    }
  }
])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below aggregation using [**`$objectToArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [**`$arrayToObject`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) aggregation  operators

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": { "map": { "$objectToArray": "$map" }}},
  { "$match": { "map.v": "value1" }},
  { "$project": { "map": { "$arrayToObject": "$map" }}}
])
```